# How can I compare thermal behaviour between two packages with an equivalent resistors circuit?

Tags: temperature, heat, thermal, maximum-ratings, power-dissipation

I want to make a thermal analysis of QFP and BGA packages for a microcontroller. I know that in terms of thermal dissipation BGA is a worse election, but I want to know how much worse it is. I don't want to use advanced software, I just want to model it like resistors. I know that this can be done, reducing all these resistors to an equivalent one. My objective is to know the temperature in ºC it will reach at maximum performing. I am bit a loss in terms of designing this circuits of resistors and where to find the values in the datasheets. Any guide?

[image]

EDIT:

I found this: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra953c/spra953c.pdf?ts=1688104597505

According to it:

[image]

I don't fully understand the meaning of that paragraph. Ok, this formula results in an extremely erroneous values and "in fact, in still-air JEDEC-defined RθJA measurements, almost 70%–95% of the power generated by the chip is dissipated from the test board, not from the surfaces of the package. Because a system board rarely approximates the test coupon used to determine RθJA" but why? It would be worse in my design than in the test board or the test board is designed to focus heat on the chip and it is always going to be better in my PCB? Equation 1 results in extremely erroneous values because the real one would be warmer or colder?

Comment: Yes, by checking the datasheet for each and comparing the thermal resistance, stated in K/W.

Comment: Calculate the power dissipation by multiplying the supply voltage with the sum of current consumption of each module in use (e.g. ADC, timers, clock generator, etc). Then, multiply this with the thermal resistance info given (hopefully) in the datasheet for each package. This will give you the **temperature rise** (\$\Delta T\$). Final temperature would be the ambient temp plus temp rise i.e. \$\ T_a + \Delta T\$. There might be different thermal resistance values such as junction-to-case or junction-to-solder point etc. Junction-to-case or junction-to-ambient will give you an idea.

Comment: @winny that only tells me what I already said: BGA is worse. I want a temperature value.

Comment: @RohatKılıç the temperature rise? do you mean from ambient temperature (to be added) or final one? So I have to multiply the power consumption by the sum of junction-to-case plus junction-to-ambiente? Is there any way of read in the datasheet power consumption in maximum performance? This would avoid me to calculate current in the modules

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics MCU datasheets tend to give the consumption for each module instead of the entire chip, as I stated in my comment. But maybe they give a maximum consumption when all the module are running. You need the check this from the datasheet of the MCU, under ELECTRICAL CHARACTERISTICS (or a similar title). If junction-to-ambient is given then everything will be easy: Junction temperature will be the temperature rise (which is the product of junction-to-amb resistance and the power dissipation) plus the ambient temperature. For example, if the total current consumption is 30 mA..

Comment: .. for 3.3 VDC supply voltage at 20 MHz then the power consumption will be 3.3 V x 30 mA = 0.1 W. If the junction-to-ambient thermal resistance is 65 °C/W then the temperature rise will be 0.1W x 65 °C/W = 6.5 °C. If the chip is running at room environment then the final die temperature will be 6.5 + 25 = ~32 °C.

Comment: Tj = P\*Rthja+Ta.

Comment: @winny I just edited the question to include a picture. In that table there is junction-to-free-air. I supose that is your Rthja, right? I still have problem to find the P for maximum performance in the microcontroller's datasheet

Comment: Correct. Nominal power at various clock speeds are sometimes listed, but can be program dependent so it’s more guidelines than absolute truth.

Comment: @RohatKılıç in the new picture, junction-to-ambient is not given. Is it the same as junction-to-free-air?

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics it is. Datasheets use \$R_{th-JA}\$ or \$R\theta_{JA}\$, so it is what you'll be using.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I thank you your explanation but according to TI's application note it seems to be wrong (?). Please check my new edit.

Comment: @winny I thank you your explanation but according to TI's application note it seems to be wrong (?). Please check my new edit.

Comment: Which is identical to what I wrote.

Comment: @winny sorry, where? Maybe you did not see the new edit

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics the excerpt you shared says the same thing. Read again my comment above starting with "MCU datasheets tend to ..." and the next one, and also winny's.

Comment: Then you need to take into account what TI took into account for what Rthja means. If pins dissipate a lot into the board, then it will affect Rthja. A given copper area is often used.

Comment: @RohatKılıç But i still don't understand what TI tries to say when it says it would result in extremely wrong results. Would be better in my PCB or worse? I don't understant the test board thing

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why you say you guys proposed the same formula if TI says that formula is wrong and the results and far from reality. But i don't know if reality is better (test board for creating the datasheet is maden to keep the chip heated) or worse (test board dissipates really well, better than mine). @winny

Comment: If you feel your measured values are more useful to you than TI’s, feel free to use those instead.